# Java map reduce - count attributes in reduce

Tags: java, apache, hadoop, count, mapreduce

I am working on map reduce. I have two data sets. I have to combine these two based on an ID and count the number of occurrences of the ID separately for each context. (For example, if it lists the data from a travel agency that operates in a few states, the output I need is of the format : User ID - count of number of visits in NY, count of number of visits in IL). That data set contains the field state: 'NY'. I have a predefined set of states(NY, IL).

While reducing it, I am always getting the count as zero though there is data. 
My output is UID 0 0 for all IDs.
Below is my code:

```
`import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.*;

import org.apache.hadoop.conf.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.*;


public class myMap {
    /* Map*/
     public static class Map extends MapReduceBase implements Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, Text> {
         public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, OutputCollector<Text, Text> output, Reporter reporter) throws IOException {
             String line = value.toString();
             StringTokenizer tokens = new StringTokenizer(line, ",");
             Boolean eventFlag = false;
             String UID = "", state = "";

             while (tokens.hasMoreTokens()) {
                 String currToken = tokens.nextToken();
                 String[] keyValue = currToken.split(":");

                 if (keyValue[0].equals( "state")) {
                         state = keyValue[1].trim();

                 }
                 if (keyValue[0].equalsIgnoreCase( "user")) {
                     UID = keyValue[1];
                 }

             }

                 output.collect(new Text(UID), new Text(state));
         }
     }

     /* Reducer*/
     public static class Reduce extends MapReduceBase implements Reducer<Text, Text, Text,Text> {
        public void reduce(Text key, Iterator<Text> values, OutputCollector<Text, Text> output, Reporter reporter) throws IOException {
            int nyCnt = 0;
            int ilCnt = 0;
            String currValue = new String();
            while (values.hasNext()) {
                currValue = values.next().toString();
                if (currValue.equalsIgnoreCase("NY")) {
                    nyCnt+=1;
                }
                if (currValue.equalsIgnoreCase("IL")) {
                    ilCnt+=1;
                }
                output.collect(key , new Text(currValue));

            }
            String counts = Integer.toString(nyCnt) + " " + Integer.toString(ilCnt);
             output.collect(key, new Text(counts) );    
        }
     }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        JobConf conf = new JobConf(myMap.class);
        conf.setJobName("myMap");
        conf.setJarByClass(myMap.class);

        conf.setMapperClass(Map.class);
        conf.setCombinerClass(Reduce.class);
        conf.setReducerClass(Reduce.class);

        conf.setMapOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
        conf.setMapOutputValueClass(Text.class);

        conf.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
        conf.setOutputValueClass(Text.class);

        FileInputFormat.setInputPaths(conf, new Path(args[0]));
        FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(conf, new Path(args[1]));


        JobClient.runJob(conf);

    }
}


`
```

Any help regarding what is wrong will be useful. Thank you.

Comment: can you post your input file

Comment: The data files cannot be shared on internet. To be more detailed about the format - there is one file userData.txt it has "UID": "xxxx" ; the other file  tourData.txt has "UID": "xxxx", "state": "NY". The output required id UID number_of_occurrences_of_UID_in_userData.txt    number_of_times_user_in_NY   number_of_times_user_in_IL